# CustomTabbedPane: stop opening of tabs that are already open

Tags: java, swing

I am using `CustomTabbedPane` in my class to show different panels within one frame. It works fine as far as functionality is concerned. I want my program to be elegant so I don't want a tab to show up, when a user click the button, that is already open. I have searched it for like more than 3 hours but didn't find anything similar to my problem. Below is my code snippet of action-listener for adding product.

```
addProduct.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Product obj=new Product();
            //if(isTabPresent()){
                obj.start();    
                mainPane.addTab("Add Product",obj);
                mainPane.setSelectedComponent(obj);
            //}
        }   
    });
```

I have also made a method `isTabPresent()` to check whether the tab is available in the mainPane(CustomTabbedPane) or not. I have commented `isTabPresent()` because it is not working the way I want.

```
public boolean isTabPresent(Object tab){ 
        for(int i=0;i<mainPane.getTabCount();i++)
            if(mainPane.getComponentAt(i).equals(tab))
                return true;
        return false;
}
```

This is what I have tried to get my job done but its not working. Any help or any better suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For better help sooner, please post a [Minimal Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. Many times, just creating the example will reveal the problem.

Comment: Where does your `CustomTabbedPane` comes from exactly? If you got access to `getTabComponentAt`, you should use that.

Comment: @splungebob I was making minimal complete example so I worked again with my class CustomTabbedPane and just to check, I made a new method that is getTitleAt(index), now instead of comparing component I am comparing only title of the tab and now it works.
Thanks a lot Sir!